# remove product-category base but still redirect to page with same permalink

Tags: permalinks, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using Woocommerce plugin, 
currently I don't set anything in "Product category base", so my woocommerce archive looks like /product-category/category2/. 
I want to remove "product-category" part away so my archive page will be /category2/
I think I can do that by set './' in permalinks settings.

But what if I already have a normal Wordpress page with a slug /category1 already and want to redirect to this page (not woocommerce /product-category/category1 without product-category) but I still want /category2 is a woocommerce archive.

- When I enter /category1 -> redirect to a normal page with this permalink (eventhough I still have /category1 archive page but not use it).
- When I enter /category2 -> redirect to Woocommerce archive category2 (because I don't have any page with the same permalink).

Is it possible to do it, I have not tried cuz I'm affraid of breaking my site.
Hope you can give me advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

https://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/

I use it with this plugin: **Code Snippets By Shea Bunge**

This allows you to modify your functions.php file without having to directly edit it. This means WordPress core and theme updates won't remove your changes.

Finally, may I suggest you try using a staging plugin to make a development version of your site so that you don't have to try things out on the live site.

Try this: **WP Staging – DB & File Duplicator & Migration By WP-Staging**

I hope that helps.

Warmly
Steve